# dictionary with a network of friends

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't know the process to do this; here is my question:

> **Modeling a network through a dictionary**
>
> For the rest, we prefer to use a social network modelling by a dictionary where the keys are given names of the people in the network and the value associated with a key is the table of friends of the person indicated by the key.
>
> From a friend table modelling the interactions between people in a network, write a `dico_reseau(friends)` function that returns a dictionary whose keys are the names of the members of the network and the values the table of their friends.

I did try mix 2 tab to create one dictionary: one for the keys and one for the values but the problem is that, I can create the tab for the keys but I don't know how link them with their values:

Example:
Joel has 3 friends. How can I give him his friends in values?

Comment: The most straightforward way to assign multiple friends to a node would be to use lists (e.g.: `{"Alfred":["Bert","Charlie"], "Bert":["Alfred"], "Charlie":["Alfred"]}`). If the network is unidirectional, your function has to ensure that all elements of each list contain the key as a friend in their own list. For directional networks, the assignment may be asymmetrical.

Comment: Please provide a _minimum_ example of the "friend table modelling the interactions between people in a network".

Answer (score 0):

When you access the dictionary using the key "Joel"
x = dictionary["Joel"]

It will return the value, which is the list of Joel's friends

Then you need to iterate through that list and run each of his friends' names in the dictionary to get their corresponding code. As you are doing that, create a new dictionary that will be your return.